# want to delete a specific node(deadlift) in firebasedatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete `deadlift` node under `name`.

[this is my firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w3JL.png)

I have tried this code:

```
Query queryRef = mReference.child("uid").child("exercise_name").orderByChild().equalTo("deadlift");
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
    }
});
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you cannot delete that item because you are using the wrong query. There are three main problems with your query. The first one is that you are passing the `"uid"` as a String and not the actual `uid` that comes from the authentication process. The second one is that you are missing two children, which is `BACK` and `name`. The third issue is that you aren't passing anything to the `.orderByChild()` method. So a correct query, in this case, should look like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query queryRef = mReference
    .child(uid) //The uid of the user
    .child("exercise_name")
    .child("BACK") //Was missing
    .child("name") //Was missing
    .orderByChild("-M2o26QvqcTmytlmact9") //The argument was missing
    .equalTo("deadlift");
```

While the above query will work, I suggest you another schema that will help you query the database more easily:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- uid
       |
       --- BACK
            |
            --- name
                 |
                 --- deadlift: true
```

And this is the corresponding query:

```
Query queryRef = mReference
    .child(uid)
    .child("exercise_name")
    .child("BACK")
    .child("name")
    .orderByChild("deadlift")
    .equalTo(true);
```